# How to set the duration for elastic follow mouse object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I´m trying to make elastic follow mouse. Everything work fine. But The only one problem: I don´t want it to bounce long time. I want to set duration to make bounce only 1 second. How to do this ?
Here is the As3 script I use:

```
var distx_L     = 0;
var disty_L     = 0;
var momentumx_L = 0;
var momentumy_L = 0;
var easing_L = 5;


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,elastic_follow)
function elastic_follow(event:Event):void {


    distx_L = myball.x - mouseX;
    disty_L = myball.y - mouseY;
    momentumx_L -= distx_L / easing_L;  
    momentumy_L -= disty_L /easing_L; 

    // dampen the momentum a little (ELASTIC)
    momentumx_L*= 0.90;
    momentumy_L *= 0.90;


    myball.x += momentumx_L-15;
    myball.y += momentumy_L;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should a matter of tweaking your values. I recommend extracting 0.90 as a variable so you can tweak it easier:

```
var distx_L:Number     = 0;
var disty_L:Number     = 0;
var momentumx_L:Number = 0;
var momentumy_L:Number = 0;
var easing_L:Number = 1;
var ease:Number = 0.5;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,elastic_follow)
function elastic_follow(event:Event):void {


    distx_L = myball.x - mouseX;
    disty_L = myball.y - mouseY;
    momentumx_L -= distx_L / easing_L;  
    momentumy_L -= disty_L /easing_L; 

    // dampen the momentum a little (ELASTIC)
    momentumx_L*= ease;
    momentumy_L *= ease;


    myball.x += momentumx_L;
    myball.y += momentumy_L;

}
```

If you want to use this sort of behaviour on multiple clips you might want to have elasticity and ease variables for each clip. Here's a lazy approach:

```
myball.mx = myball2.mx = 0;//mx for momentum on x axis
myball.my = myball2.my = 0;//my for momentum on x axis
myball.k = 4;//k for elasticity
myball.ease = .75;//ease for the final ease
myball2.k = 6;
myball2.ease = .8;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,elastic_follow)
function elastic_follow(event:Event):void {
    elasticToPos(myball,mouseX-myball.width,mouseY);
    elasticToPos(myball2,mouseX+myball.width,mouseY);
    //elasticToPos(myball2,myball.x+myball.width*2,myball.y);//you can also play with this - have the second clip chase the first rather than the mouse
}

function elasticToPos(clip:MovieClip,targetX:Number,targetY:Number):void{
    var dx:Number = clip.x - targetX;
    var dy:Number = clip.y - targetY;
    clip.mx -= dx / clip.k;
    clip.my -= dy / clip.k;
    clip.mx *= clip.ease;
    clip.my *= clip.ease;
    clip.x += clip.mx;
    clip.y += clip.my;
}
```

Notice that I've set different elasticity (k) and ease values for the two clips so they behave slightly differently. As I mentioned before playing with these values will get you desired effect.

As a side note, adding variables on the fly to the dynamic MovieClip class isn't a best practice. You should subclass Sprite and to which you add the ease/elasticity variables and an update method.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. I´ve test it almost good. but have a look at www.kazsh.com I really don´t know how he reduce that bounce of 2 brackets so amooth ! I have another object to follow the first object. and it work fine. Just can not find the way to get the smooth bounce like that ! And you can see, that bounce is only in the beginning high and after that it stop very smooth.

Comment: And here is the final test with your script. www.topzpix.com/test2.html

I have adjust many differences value on it.

It really nice script. You´ve a very clever way.
But as you can see ( compare with kazsh.com) if you move your mouse fast and test with different movement there. He has a very smooth brackets follow each other.

I got no idea how to acheive that smooth.
BUT I THINK WE´RE ALMOST THERE 1